# obtaining result of a nested loop into a list of dataframes

Tags: r, for-loop

many thanks for the comments and edits, I will try my best to provide a reproducible example. 
list_1 is a data frame with 15 columns and 33000 rows.

```
accession <- rownames(list_1)
accession2 <-sample(accession)


list <- a   b   c   d
    g_1 1   0   0   1
    g_2 0   0   1   1
    g_3 0   1   0   1
    g_4 1   1   1   0
    g_5 0   1   0   0
    g_6 1   0   0   1
    g_7 1   1   0   0
    g_8 1   0   1   0
    g_9 1   0   1   0
   g_10 0   1   1   0
```

I want to compare each column to the other column in the data frame and find the row.names that are common between them, this will be done by the function 
as.data.frame(rownames(get_intersect_members(list_1, (i), (j))))
 I want to save the result of all comparisons in out which has each comparison result stored in a list or as a column of a dataframe. 
ideally the output will look like this -

```
out <- a_vs_b   a_vs_c  a_vs_d  b_vs_c  b_vs_d  c_vs_d
       g_7      g_8     g_1     g_10    g_3     g_2
       g_9      g_6
```

I have tried this -

```
out<- vector("list", 225L)
for (k in 1:225){
for(i in accession) {
for (j in accession2){
m= as.data.frame(rownames(get_intersect_members(list_1, (i), (j))))
}
 }
out[[k]]<-m
   }
```

I can successfully run the inner for loops but I am unable to save result of each comparison.
As mentioned by Aaron my code overwrites variable m and it save the value of last comparison instead of saving each result separately.

Comment: Note that every time through the loop you're overwriting the `m` variable, that's why only the last is being saved. It's not clear from your question how you want to combine the results from the two inner loops. That's probably an easy fix, but as the above comment suggests, with more information and context we can both better help with that specific fix, and also likely suggest cleaner ways to loop.

Comment: thanks for the comments and edit, I have modified my question.